# Tool to manage and track versions of ide,programming languages,plugins etc

Tags: resources

Can you suggest a tool(if exists) to keep track of all the versions of all the resources i use to develop a project?

i.e. Project:Myproject
IDE:Eclipse
php:5.0.2
iReport Plugin:1.2.1
...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use source control: check in the binaries (or installers) for all the tools you use along with your project. When you upgrade a tool, check in the upgraded version, so the source control history includes everything that is needed to build a particular version of your project. If you want to build last year's version of the code, everything you need is then in source control.

(Disk space is cheap, so just keep a copy of everything)